# How to get project info based on owner name

Tags: c#, rally

I am using REST API C# to develop a tool. I would like to get project info based on owner name.

Does anyone have some sample code on how it should works?

Below is my code but it's not working.

```
Request ProjRequest = new Request("Projects");
ProjRequest.Workspace = "/workspace/xxx";
ProjRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
{"Name"};

ProjRequest.Query = new Query("Owner.UserName", Query.Operator.Equals, "user name");
ProjResult result = restApi.Query(ProjRequest);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following link on writing a good question and edit accordingly:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It sounds like you want to query the Project type and add a filter for Owner.UserName.  Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I just uploaded my code.

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty close.  I think you just need to change the type to be singular:

```
Request ProjRequest = new Request("Project");
```

If that is still not working, inspect the Errors collection on the response and see what's wrong...